# Angular 2- how to use external lib

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new with Angular and Angular 2, and I would like to use the following external lib in my project: 
http://angularjs.jqueryrain.com/draw-polygons-image-angularjs-canvas/

To use this lib, I have put the following line in my index.html file before angular:

```
<script src="./lib/angular-canvas-area-draw.js"></script>
```

But I have the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
at angular-canvas-area-draw.js:3
at angular-canvas-area-draw.js:234
```

How should i resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you add angular.js file in index file using <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script> ?

Comment: yes, but I have always this error!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"> must import before the any other  file in index file. Could paste the your index file and file structure?

Comment: I am using Angular2, Could you please look at the link of the lib which i want to use and let me know how can I use it ? in the link it is written that has been done for Angular 2 and as I am new with angular i am struggleing to understand how to use it, thanks

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"> </script>                                                                                                                                         
<script src="./lib/angular-canvas-area-draw.js"></script>. It should be imported like above script tag and It should work properly provide the "angular-canvas-area-draw" placed in lib and index file able to fetch the angular-canvas-area-draw from provide location

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by your tags, you are trying to use an AngularJs plugin inside an Angular application, that won't work (Or at least it would be pretty hard to get it running by using the upgrade adapter and some zonejs hacking). Try to find the plugin for Angular instead of AngularJs.

But if your tags are misleading and you're using AngularJs than make sure AngularJs in included **before** the plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/angular-canvas-area-draw.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using Angular2, Could you please look at the link of the lib which i want to use and let me know how can I use it ? in the link it is written that has been done for Angular 2 and as I am new with angular i am struggleing to understand how to use it, thanks

Comment: No you can't use it with Angular the library tags itself with AngularJs so it is not for Angular and if you read the code you'll see it's an AngularJs plugin, see: https://github.com/sedrakpc/angular-canvas-area-draw

Answer (score 0):

Move your dependencie into `.angular-cli.json` file under scripts like this

```
 "scripts": [
        ....,
        "./lib/angular-canvas-area-draw.js"
      ],
```

> from the latest angulae cli you have to add all external files(css and js) under the script and style tag in the angular-cli.json file

Comment: I can not find the file you have mentioned in my Angular 2 project! , Could you please look at the link of the lib which i want to use and let me know how can I use it ? in the link it is written that has been done for Angular 2 and as I am new with angular i am struggleing to understand how to use it, thanks

Comment: have a look at this project structur of angular 2, there you will see `angular-cli.json` file. https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-angular-cli-for-faster-angular-2-projects

Comment: I did the following steps: 
1-create a project with angular-cli
2-add the lib into .angular-cli.json file as you have said
3-add the usage part from the following link into index.html :https://github.com/sedrakpc/angular-canvas-area-draw   
but I don't see the result, any suggestion ?

Comment: No Error in the chrome console! any help ?